# Detect If new Outgoing Call Is Made From Our Application Or Not?

Tags: android, phone-call

i am developing application that makes a call from my application and detect it's different state i want to detect that call is ended or not only when call is made from my application is it possible to do so ?

Answer (score 1):

No.  THere's no info about what caused the call in the end call events.  Instead, you'd have to remember when you started a call, and ignore the end call event if you didn't start it.

Comment: how can i keep track that a call is made from my application ?

Comment: When you make the call, write a boolean to a shared preference.  When any call ends, check if that boolean is set.  Then erase it, so you don't double count.